# what is the correct way to do in show are hide case

Tags: jquery

```
        $(document).on("change",".itm_nm",function () {
        if(b.model_serial_batchno ==='M')
        {
        $('.model_hid').toggle();
        }

        if(b.model_serial_batchno ==='S')
        {
        $('.serial_hid').toggle();
        }

        if(b.model_serial_batchno ==='B')
        {

        $('.medi_view_batch_hid').toggle();
        }

        if(b.model_serial_batchno ==='D')
        {
        $('.medi_kit_expir_hid').toggle();
        }


        if(b.model_serial_batchno ==='U')
        {
        $('.medi_kit_tets_hid').toggle();
        }

        if(b.model_serial_batchno ==='W')
        {
        $('.war_hid').toggle();
        }

        if(b.model_serial_batchno ==='E')
        {
        $('.exp_hid').toggle();
        }

        })


    the above code works fine for 1 time when i select another option the previous shown are not hidding.
    What can i do in this case!!

    i created a div class to placed all divs inside .  

i cant use remove what can i do is fair if i use reload or some thing? 

on change the previous shown must be hidden if b.model_serial_batchno become false.
```

the above code works fine for 1 time when i select another option the previous shown are not hidding.
    What can i do in this case!!

```
i created a div class to placed all divs inside .
```

i cant use remove what can i do is fair if i use reload or some thing?

on change the previous shown must be hidden if b.model_serial_batchno become false.

Comment: how is your html looks like

Comment: what is `b.model_serial_batchno` and `itm_nm` -> is it a select box

Comment: do you want to change the display based on the value of the `itm_nm` element

Comment: @arun p johny yes want to change the display based on the value of the itm_nm but those values am getting from db

Comment: `b.model_serial_batchno` is the value of the `itm_nm `

Comment: is `itm_nm` a input element like a select

Comment: $(document).on("change",".itm_nm",function () {

 var prod_name = $(this).val();
 
 var pro_units = $('#i_units');
 
 var datas = {ajax:1,
   prod_name:prod_name}
   var base_url ="<?php echo base_url();?>";
   $.ajax({
     url:  base_url+"/add_stock/get_prod_procs",// 'work/getCrew',
     type: 'POST',
     data: datas,
     
     dataType: 'json',
     success: function(data)
     {
      pro_units.empty();
      
      var htm = "";
      htm+= "<option value=''>Select </option>";
      $.each(data.response, function (a, b) 
      {

      alert(b.model_serial_batchno);}

Comment: itm_nm is a select

Comment: see the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you might need is to set the display using toggle() like

```
$(document).on("change", ".itm_nm", function() {
  var value = $(this).value();
  $('.model_hid').toggle(value === 'M');
  $('.medi_view_batch_hid').toggle(value === 'B');
  $('.medi_kit_expir_hid').toggle(value === 'D');
  $('.medi_kit_tets_hid').toggle(value === 'U');
  $('.war_hid').toggle(value === 'W');
  $('.exp_hid').toggle(value === 'E');
})
```

Comment: i need to change based on b.model_serial_batchno plz find my above comment

Comment: alert(b.model_serial_batchno) based on this alert value i need to change my display

Comment: then `var value = b.model_serial_batchno;`

Comment: yes.  tried it but just displaying and getting hide autometically

Comment: since i use each i can see only last one in display is their any way to stick them on display now all are hiding expect last alert value.               $.each(data.response, function (a, b) 
{
alert(b.model_serial_batchno);
var value = b.model_serial_batchno;
$('.model_hid').toggle(value === 'M');
$('.serial_hid').toggle(value === 'S');
$('.medi_view_batch_hid').toggle(value === 'B');
$('.medi_kit_expir_hid').toggle(value === 'D');
$('.medi_kit_tets_hid').toggle(value === 'U');
$('.war_hid').toggle(value === 'W');
$('.exp_hid').toggle(value === 'E');
}

Answer (score 0):

Give a common class to all the div's you are toggling. And at the change function start, first thing you do is to hide all divs using that common class.

```
$(document).on("change",".itm_nm",function () {
    $('.hid').hide();
    //your code continues
```

Assuming, `hid` is the common class.